# Find some connection between two node in Neo4j movie database

Tags: neo4j

How can I find some connection between the Actor node with id=1100 and the Actor node with id=65731 in Neo4j graph Movie database from the neo4j sample dataset? I have tried a lot but so far I know that id 11oo is Arnold Schwarzenegger and id 65731 is Sam Worthington.When I run Cypher using ACTS_In relationship its shows no movie together.

For finding name i have used this Cypher:

```
MATCH (a:Actor {id:"1100"}),(b:Actor {id:"65731"}) 
RETURN a.name, b.name
```

For finding relationship I have used this Cypher:

```
Match(a:Actor{name:"Arnold Schwarzenegger"})-[:ACTS_IN]->()<-[:ACTS_IN]-(b:Actor{name:"‌Sam Worthington"})
using index a:Actor(name) 
using index b:Actor(name) 
return count(*)
```

I am looking for any kind of connection. Not only the same movie.

Comment: Can you paste in the actual query you tried to run? Also, are you only looking for movies where they both acted, or are you looking for other kinds of connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to find the paths between any 2 nodes, you can perform a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#_variable_length_relationships) query.

For example:

```
MATCH path=(a:Actor{name:"Arnold Schwarzenegger"})-[*]-(b:Actor{name:"Sam Worthington"})
RETURN path;
```

Note, however, that unbounded variable-length relationship queries can take a very long time to complete (or may seem to never complete), even with relatively small DBs. The best practice is to put a reasonable upper bound on the depth of the query. For example, to search for path depths of at most 5:

```
MATCH path=(a:Actor{name:"Arnold Schwarzenegger"})-[*..5]-(b:Actor{name:"Sam Worthington"})
RETURN path;
```

Comment: Since that is a totally new problem, you should create a new question. (And you should improve this current question's text, as @InverseFalcon suggested.)